# how to write a while loop in a bash file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a `while` loop in bash as below:

```
while [!(netstat -pnlt | grep ":9393" | wc -l)];
do
    echo "server not ready... waiting..."
    sleep 2
done
```

I get

> syntax error near unexpected token `netstat'

from console

what I want to do is:

to grep the service that using port 9393, count its lines. If lines number is 0,
it means the service is not running, so I will keep it wait.

**OS: debian:jessie**

please help me correct it... I looked up a lot of documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test syntax is incorrect. Have a look at the man page for usage, or at the examples all over the Internet.

```
while [[ $(netstat -pnlt | grep -c ":9393 .*LISTEN") -eq '1' ]]; do
    echo "server not ready... waiting..."
    sleep 2
done
```

But with the edit you made to your question, the following would be better:

```
while ! netstat -pnlt | grep -q ":9393 .*LISTEN"; do
    echo "server not ready... waiting..."
    sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use lsof

```
while ! lsof -iTCP:9393 -sTCP:LISTEN >/dev/null; do
    echo "server not ready... waiting..."
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: One command instead of 3. Lower usage of resources, faster run time, easier to read by humans.